# About a step in the derive of Netwon Method

Tags: optimization

I do not understand a step in the derive of Newton method in my lecture notes:

[image]

When it applies derivative on both sides of $q(x) =  f(\bar{x}) + \bigtriangledown f(\bar{x})^{T}(x-\bar{x}) + \frac{1}{2}(x-\bar{x})H(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})$

Should not it become:

$\bigtriangledown q(x) =  \bigtriangledown f(\bar{x}) + \bigtriangledown^{2} f(\bar{x})^{T}(x-\bar{x}) + \{\frac{1}{2}(x-\bar{x})H(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})\}^{'}$ ?

I do not know what the derivative of the red-box term and I also do not know why it disappears after taking derivatives.

I hope my question is clear enough. I found few books in the library and all versions of proof came like this. I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: $\bar x$ is fixed, while $x$ is the variable for the purpose of differentiating $q$.

Comment: @daw Thanks for replying but I still do not know why the term disappears.

Comment: you have to SOLVE the equation $\nabla q(x)=0$ for $x$, the derivative $\nabla q(x)$ is not zero in general.

Comment: yes, I know that I should set $\bigtriangledown q$ to be zero but my question where the derivative of $\frac{1}{2} (x-\bar{x})H(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})$ is?

Comment: this is a quadratic function in $x$ - it should not be too hard to differentiate...

Comment: @daw I believe I understand what you mean by $\bar{x}$ is fixed now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please note that $\tilde{x}$ is here a fixed point, all derivatives are taken with respect to $x$. So you get for $\nabla q(x)$:
$$ \nabla f(\tilde{x}) + H(\tilde{x}) (x-\tilde{x})$$
The first two terms on the RHS of your last equation are wrong, differentiating the first term on RHS of the equation before gives zero and the second gives 
$\nabla f(\tilde{x})$ and differentiating the third gives $H(\tilde{x}) (x-\tilde{x})$.
If you do not believe it, try it out with a simple two-dimensional quadratic function.
Ciao
Karl